# Androidアプリのアップデート手段について

Tags: android, monaca

monacaを利用して、Androidアプリ開発、既に公開を行っておりますが
アプリのバージョンアップを行う際、それを検知、
ブラウザを開きPlayストアに飛ばすようにしています。

ところがブラウザでPlayストアを開いた場合、Googleアカウントで
ログインを要求されます。
その際操作がわからない人、ログインの意味が分からない人、
そもそもアカウントを覚えてない人が多く、ログインを
通さないでアプリのアップデートを行う方法を知りたいです。
（なおアプリ本体を改修し、今後ブラウザではなくアプリのPlayストアを開くように検討中です）

すなわち、以下の制限があります。
・Playストアはブラウザで開く
・ユーザーにログイン操作をさせてはならない（クライアントの意向）
・Playストア→検索→アップデートの手順をユーザーにさせてはならない（クライアントの意向）
・アプリ本体の改修はできない（そもそもアップデートができないから改修した差分を適用できない）

この状態で、Playストアを通し、既に公開しているAndroidアプリを
アップデートする手段は存在しますか？

Comment: 既存のアプリを変更せずに変更が可能な範囲がわからないのですが……「URLをブラウザで開く」というのはPlayストアのURLがアプリ内に組み込まれてたりするのですか？それとも一度他のページに飛ばし、そこからリダイレクトしていたりするのですか？
そもそもログインが必要になる状況を知らないのですが……（あ、アプリの方で開いてもらえなかったりということ？

Comment: 「PlayストアのUR‌​Lがアプリ内に組み込まれている」です。
それがブラウザで開きます。
「アプリのPlayストア」が開く仕様ではないのです・・・

Comment: AndroidでPlayストアのURLのインテントを飛ばしたら、普通(ユーザーがPlayストアを常にブラウザで開くにしていなければ) アプリ選択が出るはずなんですが……うーん (ちなみに今はどうやって飛ばしているか、コードとかも合わせて書いてもらえますか？)